# HTML/CSS: Bottom of body cut off

Tags: html, css

Maybe it's too late at night.. I'm not sure, but I can't figure out why the bottom of my body is cut off.  I've tried playing around with margins/padding, but nothing is working the way it should.

I originally used an ID on my body element, but then decided to add an extra DIV and that's when it broke.

It gets cut off at 601px, which makes me think my margins are off, but I can't tell.  I'd like the `<div ID='index'>` to fill the entire page, but it's not.

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/QbUKN/1/

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#index {
    background: url(../img/bamboo.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
    background-color:#b0c4de;
    /*
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:-1; */
}

#profile {
    background: url(../img/lime.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}


#bird {
    z-index: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}


/******** WELCOME PAGE ********/
#indexContent {
    padding-top: 150px;
}

#welcome {
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:left;
    width: 40%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#welcome h1, h2 {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poller One', cursive;

}

#login, #signup {
    margin: 10px 60%;
    background-color: #FCFAEE;
    padding: 0 25px 20px 15px;
    border:1px solid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    /*Box shadow to make div look like it is popping off screen
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); */
}

#login h3, #signup h3 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-color: #D8D8D8;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#login .button, #signup .button {
    width: 104%;
}

.textField{
    margin: 3px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}


/******** PROFILE ********/
.fillPage {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#profileContent {
    /*background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .50);*/
    background-repeat:repeat;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 20% 0 20%;
    overflow: hidden; /* Removes background-color gap at end of page in IE */
    min-width: 600px;
}

#username {
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

#logout {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#left {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}

#right{
    margin-left: 290px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#left, #right {
    padding-top: 70px;

}

.clear{
    clear: both;
}

#stickyNav {
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    z-index: 1000;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.menuItem {
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: #FCFAEE;
    padding: 10px;
    border:1px solid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px  black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px  black;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px black;

}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    overflow: auto;
}


/******** Button Effects ********/
.button {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffe0b5;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffe0b5;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffe0b5;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #fbb450), color-stop(1, #f89306));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450 5%, #f89306 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450 5%, #f89306 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450 5%, #f89306 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450 5%, #f89306 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fbb450 5%, #f89306 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fbb450', endColorstr='#f89306',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#fbb450;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px;
    border:1px solid #c97e1c;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:6px 11px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #8f7f24;
}

.button:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f89306), color-stop(1, #fbb450));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f89306 5%, #fbb450 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f89306 5%, #fbb450 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f89306 5%, #fbb450 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f89306 5%, #fbb450 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f89306 5%, #fbb450 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f89306', endColorstr='#fbb450',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#f89306;
}

.button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="index">

<div id="indexContent">
    <div id="welcome">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <h2>MORE STUFF</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="login">
        <form name="login" action="users/profile" method="post">
            <h3>Please Sign In</h3>
            <input class="textField" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Username or Email"/><br/>
            <input class="textField" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"/><br/>
            <input class="button"    type="submit" value="Sign In"/>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="signup">
        <form>
            <h3>Sign up</h3>
            <input class="textField" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name"/><br/>
            <input class="textField" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/><br/>
            <input class="textField" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"/><br/>
            <input class="button"    type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="bird">
    <img src="img/parrot.png" alt="Parrot" />
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want your background to fill the entire page, you should leave your background styles on `body`. In your index div, you only have 601px of content in height, that's why your background cuts off at 601px.

Edit: this might be what you want.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
}
#index {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QbUKN/14/)

Comment: I was hoping you wouldn't say that.  The reason I moved the IDs to the DIV is because I am now using a PHP framework which has a common template.  Inside of the common template I have two body tags, which means I can't include a unique ID on a common template. (Unless I should ask the question of how to include unique IDs on common templates...)

Comment: [You can only have one `body` tag on a webpage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body). Why does your template have two?

Comment: @DACrosby That coudl be my issue.  I didn't notice that.  At beginning or end? Actually, jsfiddle doesn't include body tags.  What body tags are you talking about?

Comment: `<body>` at the beginning of your content and `</body>` at the end. [Here's a quick look at basic HTML page's structure.](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/page-structure)

Comment: @jbarnett Almost.  It's good on this particular page, but on another page when I scroll down it's white.  I know that `min-width: 100%` should work.  But in my case, if one page works, the other doesn't...

Comment: @Keven In your PHP framework you should be able to pass a variable to your view which you can use to give an id or class to your `<body>` element

Comment: @koala_dev I just recently began using this framework.  Is there a generic way of doing so that would work across multiple frameworks? Do you know of a resource that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Adding bottom padding to your existing `#indexContent` would be the simplest solution.

```
#indexContent {
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I agree, and I tried that already, however, that solution would be hard-coded, and I need to account for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine. Just add a small change on id 'index' and 'bird'.

```
#index {
    Display : table;
    background: url(../img/bamboo.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
    background-color:#b0c4de;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}
#bird {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience Keven. I have corrected the code please check.

Comment: Still not reaching the bottom.  Also, I want the #bird to be in a fixed position (remain at the bottom left corner of the screen).  See fiddle with your update: http://jsfiddle.net/QbUKN/26/

Comment: I corrected the issue using the jsfiddle and checked on IE. Issue was not reproduced in both of them. Now checked and corrected in firefox browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#indexContent {
padding-bottom: 100px;
padding-top: 150px;
```

}

```
#bird {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

'#indexContent' div's padding-bottom should be equal or higher than '#bird' div height

Comment: I don't like the idea of hard-coding the background's height.  What if I change the bird height to 75px?  I have a larger screen size, so adding 100px on my screen doesn't fill the whole screen.  I'd have to add around 500px for it to fill my screen.  But I want to use something like `100%` instead.